# Custom VBA Function Description Does Not Appear in Dialog Box

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I've created a custom function using VBA, and I've also created a macro that helps provide a description for users. However, the description and argument descriptions do not appear in the dialog box.

Here's an example of my custom function:

```
Function Example(First_Digit as Double, Second_Digit as Double)
  Example = First_Digit + Second_Digit
End Function
```

And here's my macro that, theoretically, should provide descriptions in the dialog box:

```
Sub RegisterUDF()

Dim strFunc As String
Dim strDesc As String
Dim strArgs() As String

  ReDim strArgs(1 To 2)
  strFunc = "Example"
  strDesc = "This is an example function."
  strArgs(1) = "Enter the first digit."
  strArgs(2) = "Enter the second digit."

Application.MacroOptions Macro:=strFunc, Description:=strDesc, Argumentdescriptions:=strArgs, _
  Category:="My Custom Category"

End Sub
```

After entering this code, this is how the dialog box appears. FYI, I am running this on a Mac. I need help to get the description and the argument descriptions to appear in this dialog box.

[image: Formula Builder]

Comment: did you run the sub? it works for me, but I am also on windows.

Comment: VBA support for Mac has always been a bit spotty. Others have run into the same issue as you: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/applicationmacrooptions-does-it-currently-work-in/d3e10c26-eab3-48ac-a4c7-2edb6967a041

Comment: "category names are ignored and you must enter a category number, which precludes defining a custom category by name" - https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304933-excel-for-mac/suggestions/11597082-full-implementation-of-the-application-macrooption

Comment: @ScottCraner I did run it, and the argument descriptions now appear -- can't believe I forgot to do that. However, the function description still is not coming up.